# Palindromic numbers, and $3$.

Tags: number-theory

Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $x'$ be the palindrome of $x$.

Why is it that $3 \mid (x - x')?$

Comment: What do you mean by palindrome?  A number is either a palindrome or it isn't.  Do you just mean reverse the digits of $x$?

Comment: @TravisJ Ah, yes! I am sorry, but I seem to be getting this all wrong. I have always called the reverse of a number its palindrome. Of course, this is wrong, and I am sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Hint :

The number $abc$ is equal to $100a+10b+c$, the palindrome number $cba$ is equal
to $100c+10b+a$

Comment: $(100a + 10b + c) - (100c + 10b + a) = (99a - 99c) = 99(a - c).$ $3 \mid 99,$ therefore $3 \mid x'?$

Comment: Yes, and you can do it for larger numbers in a similar way.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much. I am sorry if this was an easy question!

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.  For example, take $x = 13$.  Its palindrome is $x' =31$.  Then $x+x' = 44$, which is not divisible by 3.

Comment: Did you mean to apply this to *palindromic numbers*?

Comment: Even more furthermore, if $x$ is a palindromic number, it's still not true :p

Comment: if this would be applied to palindromic numbers, then it wouldn't make sense since it would either give you $2x$ or $0$.

Comment: Nothing about this question makes sense.

Comment: I am sorry about the error that I made in my question, but, now that it has been resolved, I ask that you may take a look at it, and see if you agree with it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should precise the question? What is the palindrome of x?
If $x= 110$, $x'= 011$, $x+x' = 121$.

However it is true that if $x = \sum_{i=0}^{n} 10^i x_i$ and $x' = \sum_{i=0}^{n} 10^i x_{n-i}$,

then 
\begin{equation}
x-x' = \sum_{i=0}^{n} (10^i - 10^{n-i})x_i 
\end{equation}

Now, if $i \ge n-i$, you can see that $10^i - 10^{n-i} = 10^{n-i}(10^{2i-n} - 1)$.

Otherwise, if $i \le n-i$, $10^i - 10^{n-i} = 10^{i}(1 - 10^{n-2i})$.

In all cases, $10^i - 10^{n-i}$ is of the form, $p (10^{q} - 1)$. You probably know that the rest of the division of a power of $10$ by three is always $1$.

Thereforem $3 | (10^i - 10^{n-i})$ for all $i$, and then $3|(x-x')$

Comment: You should probably elaborate on the part $3|(10^i-10^{n-i})$

Comment: oh maybe I shouldn't have given the answer straight away?